# JQuery script problem in Internet Explorer (2)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I made a script which works in all browsers, except for SOME Internet Explorer's. I cannot seem to figure out why some Internet Explorer's work, and others don't. At the office, 4 Internet Explorer 8's @ version 8.0.6001.18702 work perfectly while 4 others Internet Explorer's 8 @ version 8.0.6001.18702 (so completely the same browsers) are not working. We all have Windows XP and all the latest updates.

Please visit http://www.stardekk.be/voorontwerp/verco/ with Firefox, safari, chrome, ... and afterwards with Internet Explorer (7, 8, doesn't matter).

The problem lays within the top of the website. The thumbs should have an overlay, and when hovered; the overlay should go away and a tooltip should come up.

I hope someone can help me since 50% of the Internet Explorer's work, and 50% don't.

Thank you

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#gallery div img").after('<div class="overlay"></div>');
    $(".overlay").css({"position":"absolute", "z-index": "30", "background": "url('images/overlay.png')", "top": "0", "left": "0", "width": "241px", "height": "146px"});

    var trans = $.browser.msie ? 0.8 : 1;

    $('.overlay').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 0, function() { $(this).css("background", "transparent") });
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().css("background", "url('images/overlay.png')").fadeTo("fast", trans);
    });
});
```

Comment: The thumbs work fine in IE9 (Beta). Have you tried the Emulate-IE7 meta tag? http://davidwalsh.name/ie8-emulate-ie7

Comment: With IE7, it works for me (it's ugly because of the png, but working.) Anyway, Emulate IE-7 should be avoided. Move forward from IE6 & 7 and makes things compatible everywhere if possible.

Comment: Both IE7 and IE8 have the same problem (when the problem arises)..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace

```
$(window).load( ...
```

with

```
$(document).ready(...
```

It could come from the *connection* the window isn't loaded when you tried your script.